# Appending a sublist to another list in python

Tags: python-3.x, nested-lists

```
with open('LBP_for_paper.csv','r') as csvDataFile:
    datarows = csv.reader(csvDataFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    nofinding=[]
    rawrow=[]
    for row in datarows:
        if row[1]=='No Finding' and row[2]=='1':
            rawrow = list((row[0]+","+row[1]+","+row[2]+","+row[17]+","+row[18]))
            nofinding.append(rawrow)

    print(nofinding[:2])
```

I am reading datarows from a csv file and want to create a customized nested list based on certain columns. I want that

> list((row[0]+","+row[1]+","+row[2]+","+row[17]+","+row[18]))

shall return a list like

> ['00030805_000.png,No Finding,1,34777,69373']

which is stored in rawrow and then append to a bigger list i.e. nofinding but i am getting output as

> [['0', '0', '0', '3', '0', '8', '0', '5', '*', '0', '0', '0', '.',
>   'p', 'n', 'g', ',', 'N', 'o', ' ', 'F', 'i', 'n', 'd', 'i', 'n', 'g',
>   ',', '1', ',', '3', '4', '7', '7', '7', ',', '6', '9', '3', '7', '3'],
>   ['0', '0', '0', '3', '0', '8', '0', '4', '*', '0', '0', '0', '.', 'p',
>   'n', 'g', ',', 'N', 'o', ' ', 'F', 'i', 'n', 'd', 'i', 'n', 'g', ',',
>   '1', ',', '3', '5', '4', '0', '5', ',', '6', '3', '0', '8', '8']]

**Desired output**

> [ ['00030805_000.png,No Finding,1,34777,69373'], ['00030804_000.png,No
>   Finding,1,35405,63088'] ]

Thank you

Comment: well just run a for-loop on your final result `[''.join(i) for i in output_obtained]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `rawrow = list((row[0]+","+row[1]+","+row[2]+","+row[17]+","+row[18]))` is turning the string in to a list of characters

if you want to leave this as a comma delimited string replace that line with the following:

```
rawrow = row[0]+","+row[1]+","+row[2]+","+row[17]+","+row[18]
```

or more cleanly:

```
rawrow = ",".join([row[row_index] for row_index in [0, 1, 2, 17, 18]])
```

I am curious though why you want:

```
[ ['00030805_000.png,No Finding,1,34777,69373'], ['00030804_000.png,No Finding,1,35405,63088'] ]
```

Instead of this:

```
[ ['00030805_000.png','No Finding',1,34777,69373], ['00030804_000.png','No Finding',1,35405,63088] ]
```

which you could achieve with the following:

```
rawrow = []
for row_index in [0, 1, 2, 17, 18]:
    rawrow.append(row[row_index].split(","))
```

or in one line:

```
rawrow = [row[row_index].split(",") for row_index in [0, 1, 2, 17, 18]]
```

Furthermore, your whole code could be consolidated as follows:

```
with open('LBP_for_paper.csv','r') as csvDataFile:
    datarows = csv.reader(csvDataFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    nofinding = [",".join([row[row_index] for row_index in [0, 1, 2, 17, 18]]) for row in datarows if row[1]=='No Finding' and row[2]=='1']
    print(nofinding[:2])
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. It solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('LBP_for_paper.csv','r') as csvDataFile:
    datarows = csv.reader(csvDataFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    rawrow = []
    nofindings=[]
    for row in datarows:
        if row[1]=='No Finding' and row[2]=='1':
            rawrow = [''.join(row[row_index]) for row_index in [0, 1, 2, 17, 18] ]
            nofindings.append(rawrow)
    print(nofindings[:3])
```

Solved my issues.